# Nonconstant function with null derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ open connected and $\mathrm{D}f \equiv 0$, then $f$ is constant. Fix $p$ and every $x$ can be connected to $p$ by a polygonal path and so, apply the means value theorm in each segment.

But, if $U$ is disconnected,

> how can I find a function $f$, nonconstant, with $\mathrm{D}f \equiv 0$?

Comment: Make $f$ constant on each connected component of $U$, but different constants on different components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f:\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}\to\Bbb R$ defined by

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1,&x\in (-\infty,0)\\
1,&x\in (0,\infty)
\end{cases} $.

Can you now generalise this construction for the disconnected set  $U $?

Comment: Nice! Its really trivial.

Comment: For the general case, its enough to use the GEdgar hint. If $U$ is disconnected, we can write $U = U_{1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{n}$, where $U_{i}$ is open and $U_{i}\cap U_{j} = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$. So, define $f$ constant in each connected component. For instace, $f(x) = i$ if $x \in U_{i}$.